# Checked context doesn't exist

Tags: vb.net

Please see the code below:

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        Try

            Dim i As Long = 1000000000000000000
            Dim j As Integer = CInt(i)
        Catch ex As ArithmeticException
            MsgBox(ex.ToString)
        End Try
    End Sub
```

I throws an ArithmeticException: "Arithmetic operation resulted in an overflow.", which I would expect.

Using C# it is possible to created a checked and unchecked context (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/74b4xzyw.aspx).  If the context is unchecked then an exception is not thrown.  Is there a similar keyword for VB.NET?

I have spent some time Googling this looking at project properties etc, however I have not found an answer to my question.

Comment: Not the same since project wide: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/key2x70f(VS.71).aspx

Comment: What do you mean "a similar keyword for .NET"? Any specific language? Or do you mean IL?

Comment: You could check if `i` is greater than `Int32.MaxValue`. At least that is the best way if you neither want an exception nor an incorrect result.

Comment: @Oded, VB.NET.  Sorry.  I have updated the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

VB.NET checks for arithmetic overflows by default - so it doesn't contain any equivalent for the C# `checked` keyword.

You can set a project wide setting to make the compiler not check for these - `Remove Integer Overflow Checks`, but there is no way to make a specific bit of code as unchecked (or checked if you use this option).

See [this blog post](http://codebetter.com/grantkillian/2004/03/11/overflows-c-and-vb-net-and-il/) for some details.